# MAP and MMSE Estimations

Tags: self-learning, mean-square-error

Let the observation $x$ has the following density:
\begin{equation}
    p(x|\theta)= 
\begin{cases}
    \frac{1}{\theta},& \text{if } 0 < x \leq \theta\\
    0,              & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
and the r.v $\theta$ has:
\begin{equation}
    p(\theta)= 
\begin{cases}
    \theta \exp(-\theta),& \text{if } 0 \leq \theta\\
    0,              & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
I try to find MAP and MMSE estimation of the parameter $\theta$.

MAP:

$$
\hat{\theta} = \operatorname{argmax}_{\theta}$ $p(\theta|x) = \operatorname{argmax}_{\theta},
$$
$$
p(x|\theta)p(\theta) =  \operatorname{argmax}_{\theta} \exp(-\theta),
$$
which gives $\hat{\theta} = 0$. But it seems $p(x|\theta)$ is not well defined at $\theta = 0$. Am I missing something here?

MMSE:

$$\hat{\theta} = \mathbb{E}[\theta | x] = \int_{0}^{\infty} \theta \exp(-\theta) \,\mathrm d\theta = 1.$$

I want to verify if it's correct.

Comment: I've edited a few things for what I think you mean, let me know if I've got anything wrong :)

Comment: You must have $\theta \ge x$

Comment: @Henry How does it change the MAP solution

Comment: If $x>0$ then $\hat \theta$ cannot be $0$ and if $x>1$ then $\mathbb{E}[\theta \mid x]$ cannot be $1$

Comment: Add $x$ to your two answers.

Comment: Obviously @Henry, do you have any idea how to modify the solution according to this?

Comment: @Stacker could you please elaborate more

Comment: For the posterior distribution, $p(\theta \mid x) =0$ for $\theta \lt  x$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The posterior density is given by $$\begin{split}\xi(\theta|x)&\propto f(x|\theta)\xi(\theta)\\
&=\frac 1 \theta\textbf 1\{\theta\ge x\}\theta e^{-\theta}=e^{-\theta}\textbf 1\{\theta \ge x\}\end{split}$$

The normalizing constant is given by $$\int_x^\infty e^{-\theta}d\theta=e^{-x}$$

Thus the posterior pdf is $e^{-(\theta-x)}$ for $\theta\ge x$. You could have also gone to this directly after noting that the posterior is $\text{Exponential}(1)$ with a support starting from $x$, along with the fact that the exponential distribution is "memoryless."

This gives the mode or MAP estimate to be $x$ because $e^{-(\theta-x)}$ is decreasing in $\theta$.

The Bayes estimate (MMSE) will then be the mean of this distribution, which is $x+1$ either by direct calculation or noting that it is the mean of $\text{Exponential}(1)$ added to $x$, by similar memoryless shenanigans.

Comment: Very clear explanation @Stacker, I really appreciate it. I want to ask why don't you add another indicator function to cover the fact that $\theta > 0$. And lastly, it seems $E[\theta | x] = \int_{0}^{\infty} \theta \exp(x-\theta) d \theta = exp(x)$. Then. how did you get MMSE as $x+1$?

Comment: @eet the observation $x>0$ so $\theta>x$ is a subset of $\theta>0$. $E[\theta|x]=\int_x^\infty$ not $\int _0^\infty$.

Comment: sorry I just realized that now. thanks.

Comment: @eet I never really thought about it tbh. Indicator $\theta\ge x$ is needed because the likelihood should be 0 if $\theta<x$. (It is not a possible value of $\theta$, so we want to reject it immediately.)